# Jmeter: 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I was trying to issue a https request through jmeter and observed am getting below response.

```
<html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p>This document you requested has moved temporarily.</p>
```

And it seems the actual url redirecting to different url which is getting the Response Code 200 which is OK. [The first urls response code is 302]

Also I have given an assertion for the page being loaded, but still that assertion fails [when I saw the response data in HTML format, observed that the respective page is not loaded]

Any help in resolving this issue would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion

If you chose "**Main sample and sub samples**" it will include the responses from the redirects. So for example if you're searching for "string" it will also include the response from the redirected page.